# deploy a war file on apache tomcat issue : no permission for reading/writing a file

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

i have this problem since a while,

i have a web,that can  `read files from many server.`

when it running from eclipse..all is well.
the problem is that when i've published the web on `apache tomcat`..i cannot read the file on server(`permission issue`)
i change the username and password for the apache to give it all privileges.
i noticed that the only time i haven't access to read a file,its when the server machine has password protection sharing.
i cannot turn off this password,how to solve it throw the code.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "i change the username and password for the apache to give it all privileges"?.

If it works from eclipse and from tomcat it doesn't, then it must be the tomcat user that doesn't have read/write permissions for that file you are trying to access.

By default, the tomcat user is "tomcat7", so what you have these options:

1) Change the file locations permissions (not recommended):

```
chmod 666 "myFile"
```

or:

```
chown tomcat7:tomcat7 "myfile"
```

2) (best option!) Change the tomcat user and group, and run tomcat as your os user or any other which has permissions. If you are using tomcat 7 then the config file must be in  `/etc/default/tomcat7`:

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i didn't get it..i am working on a windows machine (windows 8). btw this is the way how i have changed apache username and password :[http://superuser.com/questions/301864/run-tomcat-service-as-different-user-on-windows-7] .

Comment: Ok, please in this case specify the operating system, It is not very likely to use what you are using under windows.. For windows, I cannot help su much.. Sorry :(